# Issue rendering on fresh install of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio 1.0.1 on Windows 7, created a new project and am getting errors galore.
First and foremost, the rendering for my layout preview gives me the following stack trace:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Could not find the bundle com/ibm/icu/impl/data/icudt50b/
at com.ibm.icu.impl.ResourceBundleWrapper.getBundleInstance(ResourceBundleWrapper.java:109)
at com.ibm.icu.util.UResourceBundle.instantiateBundle(UResourceBundle.java:573)
at com.ibm.icu.util.UResourceBundle.getBundleInstance(UResourceBundle.java:145)
at com.ibm.icu.util.UResourceBundle.getBundleInstance(UResourceBundle.java:108)
at com.ibm.icu.impl.ICUResourceTableAccess.getTableString(ICUResourceTableAccess.java:23)
at com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale.getCharacterOrientation(ULocale.java:1755)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.isLocaleRtl(Bridge.java:424)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:241)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:688)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:677)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:677)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:815)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

My activity's Java file also riddled with "Cannot resolve symbol 'x'".
It seems like I'm missing files, perhaps in my Java version, or in my Android sdk.
I'm not even sure where to start in resolving this. Thanks for any ideas you have.

Comment: Check this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099051/android-and-icu-5-0>

Comment: You can do "File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart" option to fix this. You can also try Build -> Project Clean.  You can also try doing a rebuild from the command line.  I feel your pain, it took me a day to import an project that was working fine in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things come to mind that could fix the issue.

One is that you may have an issue with your current Java JDK, so try using the most recent version of the Java JDK. Currently I am using version 8 update 25 (64-bit). I also have the most recent version of regular Java, also in version 8 update 25 (64-bit).

If that checks out and you are still getting the same problem then I would uninstall android studio and then re-install it.

If you are still having problems do the uninstall again but this time install Android Studio in a different directory, outside of both program files directories. This will avoid some of the native security measures in windows 7, which may or may not be causing your problem in the first place.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Uninstalling, and then re-installing outside of Program Files did it for me. It seems the files I was missing were in the SDK files, but Windows was doing something that was preventing me from updating my SDK. After messing around with the target/build SDK in the manifest, it seemed they were all broken.
Re-installed directly on C drive, specified a new path to SDK files and viola, everything is functioning.
Thanks!